# Is there any chance to check the availability of a table in suppression section

Tags: crystal-reports

i want to suppress a section in crystal based on table value.But some times table1(tt_customer) is not available then i want to check for another table . for example like 
if avail(tt_customer) then 
something
else if avail(tt_order) then
something

please help me.
Thanks In advance.

Comment: Can you explain more on table availability? as far as know in CR tables are added in database expert in adavance.

Comment: I am displaying product details in a report. I divided the details of a product in to section because i want to suppress some section based on there availability.In one section i am writing as
 if (({tt_CEAdditionalDoc.docnumber}= maximum ({tt_CEAdditionalDoc.Docnumber}, {tt_Product.ProductCode})) and 
  ({tt_ProdAttribute.attnumber} = maximum ({tt_ProdAttribute.attnumber}, {tt_Product.ProductCode})) and
   ({tt_ProdRework.reworknumber}= maximum ({tt_ProdRework.reworknumber}, {tt_Product.ProductCode}))) then
false
else
true

Comment: but some product dont have {tt_CEAdditionalDoc.docnumber} details (no data for that product) then above conition is failing. that why
 i want to check the availability of that table so i can change the condition based on that.

Comment: Try using `IsNull({tt_CEAdditionalDoc.docnumber})` before using the `If` condition

Answer (score 0):

Crystal Reports can *only* check the value of a field--it cannot check if a table exists or if a field exists.

Suggestion: Create a `boolean` parameter that your application's logic will set, then use it in the section's conditional-suppression logic.

```
// the section's conditional-suppression formula needs to return TRUE or FALSE
{?suppress}
```